# Get the camera/device orientation when another app is on top with locked orientation

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, camera, android-camera2

I am working on an application where it will capture images in the background.

I am able to rotate the captured image using the below code:

```
var angle = windowService!!.defaultDisplay.rotation

private fun rotate(
        pictures: TreeMap<String?, ByteArray?>?,
        angle: Float
    ): TreeMap<String?, ByteArray?> {
        val rotatedPictures: TreeMap<String?, ByteArray?> = TreeMap()
        val size = pictures?.size ?: 0
        for (i in 0 until size) {
            val key = pictures?.keys?.elementAt(i)
            val byteArrayImage: ByteArray? = pictures?.get(key)

            //convert bytearray to bitmap
            val source: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(
                byteArrayImage, 0, byteArrayImage?.size ?: 0
            );

            //rotate image
            val matrix = Matrix()

            matrix.postRotate(angle)

//            LogUtils.i(TAG, "currentRotation Angle - $angle")
            val rotatedBitmap: Bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                source, 0, 0, source.width, source.height,
                matrix, true
            )

            //convert bitmap to bytearray again
            val stream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            rotatedBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream)
            val rotatedByteArray: ByteArray = stream.toByteArray()
            rotatedBitmap.recycle()
            rotatedPictures.put(key, rotatedByteArray)
            stream.flush()
            stream.close()
        }
        return rotatedPictures
    }
```

the problem I am facing now is when an application is running on a device with a locked orientation (let's say portrait) but the device is in landscape position. so, using this code I am getting portrait as orientation instead of landscape due to which the image gets rotated to 90/270 degrees.

Is there any way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should achieve this by giving device orientation from the sensor like this

```
     val orientationEventListener: OrientationEventListener =
        object : OrientationEventListener(this) {
            override fun onOrientationChanged(orientation: Int) {
                changeOrientation(orientation)
            }
        }
   private var screenOrientation: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()


 private fun changeOrientation(int: Int) = when (int) {
    in 0..50 -> {
        //portrait
        screenOrientation.value = 0
    }
    in 50..130 -> {
        //landscape 90 deg
        screenOrientation.value = 1
    }
    in 130..230 -> {
        //portrait
        screenOrientation.value = 2
    }
    in 230..315 -> {
        //landscape 180 deg
        screenOrientation.value = 3
    }
    else -> {
        //portrait
        screenOrientation.value = 0
    }

}
```